# Problem restoring a 2005 SQL DB with 2008

Tags: sql-server-2005, backup, sql-server-2008-express, database-restore

I have a DB I created with SQL Server 2005 and created a backup (*.bak) now I want to restore it with 2008 but ouch, I get the following error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Restore failed for Server 'SHIMMY-PC\SQLEXPRESS'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.0.1600.22+((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Restore+Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.0.1600.22+((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414+)&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Comment: I'd suggest renaming this. As J.W. mentioned, it really doesn't have anything to do with SQL 2005 to SQL 2008. I had the exact same problem with 2008  to 2008.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you did the original backup, the 'Destination' window had two different paths listed.  You selected one, assuming that the backup would use only that one path.  What actually happened was that the backup striped itself onto both paths - half the backup onto each.  The restore message you are getting is because the restore wants both halves of the backup, but can only find one.

Comment: so what do we do, am I deep or not?
is there any solution?

Comment: not unless you can find the other file; you really only have half the data right now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a 2008 problem, can you install the backup back to sql 2005.

Check out this [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/abf50e00-c9b0-4809-9e61-43ed8a53e968/).

Comment: I checked out, I assume I am in deep shoot, I posted a reply right there (it should be last reply now).
Thanks anyway.